# FTB Direwolf20 pack automatic ME Crafting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I want to make an me system that crafts cobblestone in compressed cobblestone if you have more than 2 stacks of cobblestone, then crafts that compressed cobblestone in double compressed cobblestone etc. I tried several ways to do this, but none worked. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Right now i have a system that uses auto workbenches, but that is unhandy and really slow

Answer (score 0):

Set up a level emitter so that it emits a redstone signal when the network has 2 stacks of cobble and next to that put an export bus that exports cobble to a fabricator with the compression recipe and then an import bus to get the compressed cobble out.

Depending wether you want the intermediate compression states available to you, if you don't: Just import all compressed cobble into a next fabricator (set to make the next compression) and extract the output, that for all compression levels, or do the same thing with other pipes etc (to decrease load on AE network), if you do: put level emitters on all the import buses so they emit a signal only when 9 of that compression state is available.

You might also want to adjust the first level emitter since it may not respond fast enough and may use more cobble then desired.